# Unable to access session variable in php script called using ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Consider the following scenario. I have three php files, file1.php, file2.php and file3.php located on my server.
file1.php starts a session and sets a session variable say,var.
I am able to access var using $_SESSION['var'] in file2.php. file3.php is called using jquery ajax functionality, but im unable to access $_SESSION['var'] in file3.php. if i do a gettype($_SESSION['var']) in file3.php it returns NULL.
What could be the problem here ?

Please help
Thank You

Comment: can you post file3.php. Make sure you have started session in file3.php

Comment: Yeah, i have session_start() in all three files

Comment: can you upload your js and file3.php file

Comment: http://pastie.org/1182465 .If i directly call file3.php,it is able to access the session variables, but not when called asynchronously using ajax.

Comment: From where are you calling file3.php ie where is your ajax query

Comment: The Ajax request is made in file2.php

Comment: upload the ajax request part ;)

Comment: I don't get it. in file3.php you're writing gettype($jhg) to a file, but $jhg isn't being set anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

From my tests it should work. What could be happening is if you do not have sessions set to use cookies and they are being appended to the url, you would need to pass the session hash via GET, using the proper name set in the php.ini, to the uploadify script.

But there are a bunch of inconsistencies, especially in that pastie, you do not necessarily have to rename every part of your code, just need to post the relevant sections.